# How to deal with setting values for a multi-layer JSON in data in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

here is a form in the `data` of my Vue component `childEle`:

```
data:{
  form:{
    root1:Number,
    root2:{
      child1:[],
      child2:{},
      child3:String
    },
    root3:[],
    root4:{
      child4:string,
      child5:[]
    }
  }
}
```

It is a very complex `JSON Object`. Since it's bidden with the `form` in `iView`, it seems impossible to flatten this `JSON Object`. Now I need to set values to this form once I open this component(in fact it's a `Modal`), so I transfer value from the parent element by `props`:

```
props:{
  outForm:{
    type:Object,
    default: function () {
      return {}
    }
  }
  ……
}
```

And add the attribute `watch` to it:

```
watch:{
  outForm(val){
    this.form = val
  }
}
```

Now a problem occurred. I also bonded a `value` attribute to control displaying the `Modal` or not, but when I transfer value to `value` attribute the `value` in `data` didn't change, it failed to close the `Modal`, even if I called `this.$forceUpdate()`.
How to deal with it? Thanks for yours help!

Answer (score 1):

Your control about showing or hidding the modal doesn't need to stay in your modal component.

An option is threat the modal as always active and control it with v-if condition inside the parent, for example in a variable called `showModal`.

So, the parent sets true when user does the action to show the modal and on the other hand, modal emits an close event (`this.$emit('close')`), catched inside the parent (`<child-component @close="hideModal" />`) and setting `showModal` to false.

But if you really need to put this variable inside the form, maybe [reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) helps